# pickerDidSettle() not called

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

In one of my Watch Extension's interface controllers I have several `WKInterfacePicker` elements, and I need to know when the user has selected a value. According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1628205-pickerdidsettle), `WKInterfaceController` should be able to implement `pickerDidSettle(_:)` method that has the corresponding picker element as parameter. For some reason the method never gets called when I use the pickers. Here is the basic structure of my implementation:

```
override func pickerDidSettle(picker: WKInterfacePicker) {
    // Code inside this block is not called
}
```

If I mark the function with an `@IBAction` attribute and connect them with the picker elements in interface builder, the instance method works. However, this apparently prevents me to assign picker actions that receive all the picker values through which the user is scrolling.

```
@IBAction
override func pickerDidSettle(picker: WKInterfacePicker) {
    // This function gets called, but blocks other actions
}
```

My interface controller inherits from WKInterfaceController and conforms to two custom protocols. How should I implement the method?

Edit: The issue was related to a possible bug in WatchKit, where `pickerDidSettle(_:)` will not be called without an existing @IBAction connection to the controller. I assume it is a bug, because related instance methods `pickerDidFocus(_:)` and `pickerDidResignFocus(_:)` work independent of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue occurs, when something gets 'out of sync' between Xcode and the Simulator.

Just close the Simulator and clean and rebuild your app (via 'Product/Clean Build Folder') to recreate the 'sync.